# How to remove a character from a string until certain index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have the following string "........my.python.string" and I want to remove all the "." until it gets to the first alphanumeric character, is there a way to achieve this other than converting the string to a list and work it from there?

Comment: `s.lstrip(".")` removes all leading dots. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I believe this is the best way to do so. You should make this an answer.

Comment: @Olivier I wouldn't do this, as this was asked a thousand times already, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
s = "........my.python.string"
new_s = re.sub('^\.+', '', s)
print(new_s)
```

Output:

```
my.python.string
```